# Curl Vector Fields

Tags: vector-fields

Quite a simple question:

$\textbf{u} = (a\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z), b\sin(x)\sin(y)\cos(z), c\sin(z))$ is a curl vector field. Which of the following may correctly be deduced?

A: None of the Above

B: $c = 0$, but $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary;

C: $c = 0$, and $a = b$;

D: $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all arbitrary

E: $a = 1$, $b = 1$ and $c = 0$;

I believed the correct answer to be D, however, I know now that the correct answer is C. But I don't know how this can be deduced?

Comment: Could you please define the term "curl vetor fields"? Are you referring to the curl of the above function?

Comment: When you say that $\textbf{u}$ is a "curl vector field", do you mean that $\textbf{u}$ is the curl of some vector field?

Comment: "We say that a vector field is a curl vector field if it is the curl of some other vector field A = grad x B" (just from my lecture notes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the properties of curl vector fields. Let $\textbf{u} = \nabla \times\textbf{f}$

Now, we know that

$$\nabla \cdot\textbf{u} = \nabla\cdot(\nabla \times\textbf{f}) = 0$$

$$\implies -a\sin x \cos y\cos z + b\sin x \cos y \cos z + c\cos z = 0$$

Since this is an identity, it means that this should be true for all $x,y,z$

$$\implies \cos z \left(c + (b-a) \sin x \cos y\right) = 0$$

Now for this to be true for all $x,y,z$, we have

$$c = 0, a=b$$

Comment: Why does it follow that dot(grad,u) = dot(grad,dot(grad,f)) = 0?

Comment: Divergence of curl fields are identically zero